# GraphQL multiple queries in one request

Tags: graphql

I have some groups created by users in my database. Each group has multiple members in it. This is what a typical group looks like:

```
{
    "groupName": "some-group-name",
    "userIds": ["001", "002", "003"]
}
```

I also have a separate node of users in my database. This is what a user looks like:

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "userName": "some-unique-username"
}
```

I want to list every single group and its members. So, it would be:

- group1

  - user1 id; user1 name;
  - user2 id; user2 name;
- group2

  - user3 id; user3 name;
  - user4 id; user4 name;

and so on...

How would it be possible (if at all) to fetch these groups and their user ids and also query for users by id and return a single JSON containing all the data only with one request?

Right now I'm just fetching some amount of groups and iterating over the `userIds` of each of them and sending a request for each user separately.
I'm not asking about pagination or simple querying, I just want to get every group and the users inside those groups.

Comment: hard to understand your question. regardless of the technology, is this what you are looking for f(userid) -> group ? then what about user(id:"xxx") { username group }

Comment: @OlivierRefalo made an edit, is it clearer or should I elaborate more?

Comment: @OlivierRefalo >then what about user(id:"xxx") { username group }

user nodes don't store the groups they're in. Groups store user ids that I want to query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

What I needed to do was to create a separate resolver for fetching members of each group:

```
resolvers: {
    ...
    Group: {
        members: (group, _, context) => group.members.map(memberId => context.db.findUserById(memberId)
    }
    ...
}
```

The parent group object is passed as the first argument to the resolver so when I query:

```
{
    groups(count: 10){
        name
        members {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the names of the first 10 groups along with its members' names.

Answer (score 1):

With the following schema,

```
type User {
   name: String
   firstName: String
   location: String
}

type Group {
   groupname:String!
   users:[User!]
}

type Query {
   groups:[Group!]
   group(name: String): Group
}
```

the following query:

```
{
groups
 {
  groupname
  users {
       name
       firstName
       location
  }
 }
}
```

could return

```
{
  { name: "group1",
    users: [{name:"user1", firstName:"firstName1", location:"Localtion1"},
    {name:"user2", firstName:"firstName2", location:"Localtion2"}]
  },
  { name: "group2",
    users: [{name:"user1", firstName:"firstName1", location:"Localtion1"}]
  },
  ...etc..
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: What I'm asking is if it's possible to get the user's info using the user's id without sending each request separately. In this case I still have to do it.

So, if I want to list the names of every user inside a group, I would still have to send another request to get the names of every user. Can't I just do that with one query?

Comment: altered to match requirements. one request, graphql is just like sql, the client decides what it wants...

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't answer my question, but I figured it out myself and will post an answer asap